# System keeps asking me for root password instead of my password!

Tags: linux-mint

On a brand-new install of Linux Mint (latest version fwiw), and whenever I want to do something that requires root privileges (change date/time, update-manager,...) it asks me for root password (which does not work as I have none) instead of my own password (which *would* work as my users is in sudoers).

There is always a workaround by running things with an explicit sudo from commandline... but this sucks... any fix?

Comment: I'm not sure if Mint currently uses gksu for elevated privileges in these situations, but if it does you may need to run `gksu-properties` and make sure that the mode is set to `sudo` rather than `su`

Answer (score 1):

The fix is to prepend `sudo` to the command. That's the way Mint works. If you don't start with sudo, it will ask you for root privileges, and the only way it can get those is to have you put in the root password.

You can also run something like `sudo bash` once and the run all your root commands inside that shell, but I really don't recommend doing so. It's a bad practice to get into.

Comment: actually `sudo su` is better than `sudo bash`

Comment: Better, yes...  but still bad practice.

Comment: AFAIK the only possibility if `root` has no password set (and not logging in via passwordless `ssh` as `root`)

Comment: No, another options - and the best practice IMHO - is to prepend each command with `sudo`.

Comment: Well, that of course is better if you tend to type faster than you think - happened to me often enough. But then the `timestamp_timeout` should also be set to `0`.

Comment: `sudo -i` also give you a root-shell (alternative to `sudo bash`).  Be sure your username (the one you intend to be able to use `sudo` for administrative tasks) is a member of the `sudo`-group (it used to be the administrators-group, but now it's the sudo-group),

Comment: This is not a solution, as @John wrote explicitly: "..There is always a workaround .. with .. sudo", and asked for a solution

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the following: as a regular user, write

```
$ sudo passwd
```

It will asks you for *you own* password, and then it will offer you to set a new password for *the root*.

I actually believe that this deserves to be called a Linux Mint bug, and filed. I have encountered it in Linux Mint XFCE multiple times.